# Citation undefined TexWorks can't find my bib file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, texworks

I tested this files both on TexWorks and overleaf, but my citation is always [?, ?, ?].

> Running BibTex does not help, and I get the information:
> miktex-bibtex: warning: running with administrator privileges I
> couldn't open file name `bibliography.aux'

This is my tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                      
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[polish,british]{babel} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[page]{appendix} 

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing


\frenchspacing

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language={},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\lst@ifdisplaystyle\color{blue}\fi,
    commentstyle=\color{gray}
}


\begin{document} 


\chapter{Introduction}
 \cite{bib:article,bib:book,bib:conference})


%%%%%%%%%%% bibliography %%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}


\end{document}
```

And this is my bibliography.bib:

```
@Book{bib:book,
  Title                    = {Title of a book},
  Author                   = {Name Surname and Name Surname},
  Publisher                = {Publisher},
  Year                     = {2017},
  Address                  = {Hong Kong},
  ISBN                     = {83-204-3229-9-434}
}


@Article{bib:article,
  Title                    = {Title of an article in a journal},
  Author                   = {Surname, Name and Nama Surname},
  Journal                  = {Journal Title},
  Year                     = {2016},
  Number                   = {8},
  Pages                    = {1092--1113},
  Volume                   = {157}
}


@InProceedings{bib:conference,
  Title                    = {Title of a conference article},
  Author                   = {Name Surname and Surname, Name and N. Surname},
  Booktitle                = {Conference title},
  Year                     = {2006}, 
  Pages                    = {5346--5349}
}
```

Comment: You have to run `bibtex` using the name of the TeX file (without extension), not the name of the bib file

Comment: @Guido didn't help, but I just made new bibliography in the .tex file using the example from: [link](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/bibliography_management_with_bibtex#Bibliography_management_with_Bibtex) and removing \usepackage[page]{appendix}.

Comment: Tested the example on Overleaf and it works properly